# Download contacts from a Nokia 2600 Classic with a broken screen

Tags: data-recovery, bluetooth, nokia-pc-suite

A family member dropped his Nokia 2600 Classic phone and while it's still possible to turn it on, and even make calls, its screen stays completely black the whole time. Obviously, we bought a new phone, but sadly, all the contacts were saved into the broken phone's memory (rather than the SIM card), and now we struggle to recover them.

When I used that phone years ago, connecting it to a PC over bluetooth was an easy and straightforward way to get phone numbers and SMS messages out of it using the PC Suite software. But with the screen broken, pairing the phone with a computer became a challenge.

I considered buying a data cable, but that turned out to be basically impossible for such an old phone (or at least that's what half an hour of searching revealed). As for bluetooth, if I knew someone having an identical phone, or a website where the menu structure of old Nokia phones are documented, maybe I could blindly activate the proper menu item (by entering the right "combination", like "Menu, down, down, OK, down, down, down, OK... I hope you get the idea :))

And that leads to my question:

- Could someone please having such a phone telling me where in the menu structure the Bluetooth option is?
- Can I initiate the bluetooth pairing in such a way that the pairing code appears on the computer's screen (because then I can easily enter that on the phone), rather than the other way around (which would be basically impossible because I wouldn't see the code the phone generates on the broken screen)?
- Is there any other way of grabbing the contacts that I didn't think of? (E.g. I could pop in a SIM card and have the phone copy the numbers there, but again, I would need to be able to navigate the menus "blindly" to do that.)

Thank you!

Comment: Removed the "product recommendation" part of my question (i.e. where I asked if there's a site where Nokia menu structures are documented, which has been a tiny part of it anyway). I think I have described a concrete situation and asked a very specific question, and shared my research in how I tried finding the answer to it. If my question still doesn't fit the rules, please explain, because I don't see how it doesn't fit the style of questions on this site, or why is it categorized as a question seeking "recommendations".

Comment: “Nokia 2600 Classic“ appears to use a micro-USB to Type-B cable.  However, it appears you would still have to navigate a menu, even if you had one.  Questions about Nokia phones are out of scope.

Comment: While now I see how this question was off-topic for SuperUser, since it's still here, I thought it might be useful to someone if I told how I ended up solving it (in case someone finds it with a search engine or something): I purchased an identical – but working – phone for about $3 (second hand of course), and used it to "learn" navigating the Contacts menu "blindly". With that knowledge, I was able to copy all contacts to a SIM card from the broken phone, and that was it.